# .NET/Mono framework targeting

Tags: .net, windows, linux, frameworks, mono

Assume I have 2 machines, one machine with MS windows with .NET 4.0 and the other begin a linux machine with Mono 2.10.1
Now I create a command line application on the respective machines that will output the installed framework version using:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
```

**Question 1**

Is my assumption correct that the following should be displayed:
Windows : 4.0.30319.1
Linux : 2.10.1 (or something similar??)

**Question 2**
Assuming we have both mono and ms.net installed on a windows machine, is there a way to specify that an exe must run on the mono framework in windows? (perhaps a config file?)

**Question 3**
If I compile a (simple) mono application on a linux machine, will that compiled exe work on a windows machine with only ms.net installed?

Comment: I would try using some VMware machines.

Comment: My questions has been answered correctly by 2 different people . Who do I give the green tick to???

Comment: I would try the one with the lower reputation points to give him a rise :-)

Comment: Cheers gents! I upvoted Ekkehard rightaway when he came up with the missing bit of the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

- Question 1  (test.cs below[1]), tested on linux:

.

```
mono.2.6.7 $ ./test.exe 
2.0.50727.1433
$ source custom/MONO/devenv.sh 
mono.2.11 $ dmcs test.cs
mono.2.11 $ ./test.exe 
WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
Using default runtime: v1.1.4322
1.1.4322.2032
mono.2.11 $ mono ./test.exe 
4.0.30319.1
mono.2.11 $
```

- Question 2

  You could make a batch file to invoke `mono.exe myapplication`. Look in %PROGRAMFILES%\Mono 2.10\bin for plenty examples
- Question 3
  Yup

For compatibility check the other way around (check for implementation stubs, missing P/Invoke functionality etc.) there is the [MoMa tool](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA)

---

**test.cs**

```
using System;

namespace X 
{ 
  class Y 
  {
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(Environment.Version);
      return 0;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Updated with output of Version on mono  2.6.7 .NET 2.0 and mono 2.11 .NET 1.1 and 4.0

Answer (score 5):

ad Question 1: you should expect the version of the Runtime, not of Mono

Answer (score 0):

For Question 2: You can default runtime to mono on windows environment for Xamarin studio.

You can mono run time from here:

Xamarin Studio => Tools => Options =>  Projects => .NET Runtimes => Add (add mono here)

and mark mono as default runtime.